# Rails - Bootstrap - styling link_to content

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am having an awful time trying to get a grip on rails.

I'm tearing my hair out trying to understand why my CSS won't apply to a link_to bit of content.

I have a form, where users can write posts. I then display those posts on a show page, and an extract of them on one of the key pages. That extract is stored in a partial in my article folder called _extract.html.erb.

It has the following content:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <% Article.all.in_groups_of(2) do |group| %>
      <div class="row">
        <% group.compact.each do |article| %>
            <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
              <div class="indexdisplay">
              <%= image_tag article.image_url, width: '100%', height: '200px' if article.image.present? %>
                  <a class="extracttitle"><%= link_to article.title, article %> </a>
                <div class="intpol3">    <%= truncate(article.body, :ommission => "...", :length => 250) %></div>
                 </div>
            </div>
              <% end %>
              </div>

    <% end %>

  </div>
</div>
```

On the key page I then include that partial with: <%= render 'articles/extract' %>

The styling on the article page itself is working fine, with:

```
<div class="intpol3" style="text-align: left; font-size: 17px; padding-top:10px; color: #003366">
                    <%= @article.title %>
                </div>
```

That section also works fine when I make the div class=extracttitle

Extracttitle is a CSS class defined as:

```
.extracttitle {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  color: #003366;
  margin-top: 5px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-align:left; 
  padding-left:1px;
  a:link {text-decoration:none; background-color:transparent; color: #003366;};
  a:visited {text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent; color:#003366;};
  a:hover {text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent; color:#E50851;};
  a:active {text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent; color:#003366;};
}`
```

When I render this page, the content displays with all the css except the title is overridden by something in the standard set up which is applying ugly styling on the a link.

I can't figure out how to override it.

I have tried a div tag, I have tried putting html_options inside the link tag. Nothing is working.

How do you put CSS on the content of a link to tag in rails? I feel like this should have a simple solution. I have tried more than 20 variations and can't find a solution.

My CSS files are set up as follows:

application.css.scss

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

framework_and_overrides.css.scss

```
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "bootstrap-slider";
```

custom.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

I have a file called articles.css.scss which is where those files are stored. Maybe there is something to the comment below about the order things are loaded. If the files are loaded alphabetically, the c for custom comes after articles.

Comment: is your .extracttitle {blah blah} defined in application.css.scss?

Comment: it's in articles.css.scss

Comment: move it to application.css.scss and see what happen .. As a part of debugging process .

Comment: you need to close this too  , like so :   /* *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */

Answer (score 0):

The css files for bootstrap are hidden from you by default, assuming you are using a gem. That is probably what needs to be looked at

I would recommend taking a look at the [Railscast for bootstrap](http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics), as it shows it, but the docs at https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails also point out the following command that will force the css files

```
rails g bootstrap:themed [RESOURCE_NAME]
```

Hope that gets you in the right direction

Comment: Hi, I don't use that gem. I use: gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5.1'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.4.0'
gem 'bootstrap-slider-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'

Comment: so are you able to see the bootstrap css files?

Comment: bootstrap works fine everywhere else im my app. its something to do with the link tag I think

Comment: How about "<%= link_to article.title, article, class: "extracttitle" %>

Comment: No -it doesnt work. When I inspect element on it, it references a extracttitle, but it displays media all a (it doesnt even show extractttile css in the style view panel

Answer (score 0):

Let's test it and see what happens:

1. Restructure your DOM from:

`<a class="extracttitle"><%= link_to article.title, article %> </a>`

to:

`<%= link_to article.title, article, class: "extracttitle" %>`

Refresh and see what's going on, if not working follow step 2

2. Make sure you include your css after bootstrap, check your application.scss file, should be something like

application.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "framework_and_overrides"
@import "custom" /* don't import bootstrap inside this file. */
```

3. Add `!important` to your css file

add this line

`color: red !important;`

inside your `.extracttitle{}` and see if text change to red

Comment: Hi Wayne, I've already tried the first section. That doesn't change anything.

Comment: You might be on to something with step 2. See my file structure above. You think I should change things around?

Comment: Hi @user2860931, I updated the `application.css.scss` file, you should take a look, best practice is not to required tree . in `application.css.scss`, and also if you use `.scss` you should use `@import`. Try it first and tell me what you see.

Comment: Hi Wayne, but if I change application.css.scss to the way you have it, what's left to go in custom? Also, if I remove the tree, how do all the other files in the stylesheets folder get incorporated?

Comment: Hi, you should import only css files you want to use but not all files from your folder. If your `custom.scss` has no more code there, you can just delete it or don't import it.

Comment: all of the ones in the css list above have styles in them, including the links styling. except its not working

Comment: Yep  - my file currently looks like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34192056/rails-4-styling-css-with-bootstrap-sass

Comment: doesn't matter what colour i try and the 'important' doesn't change it either