# Rails 4 - Styling CSS with Bootstrap Sass

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble configuring my app to work with css.

I am using Bootstrap CSS, through the bootstrap sass gem. I have the following gems installed:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5.1'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.4.0'
gem 'bootstrap-slider-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
```

My stylesheets folder is configured as follows:

application.css.scss

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *


 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

appliccustom.css.scss

```
 @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
    @import "bootstrap";
```

applicframework_and_overrides.css.scss

```
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "bootstrap-slider";
```

various other resource specific css files (e.g.: profile.css.scss)

I have named the above files in the way I have to try to get all the files which import bootstrap to the top of the alphabetical tree, but after application.css.scss) I'm not sure whether this is helping anything.

For the most part, my styling works. However, I'm having trouble with getting the styling to work on link tags and I'm not sure if its because of the ways (I've tried more than 20 variations) of putting css on content or maybe the way the css files are configured.

I've read lots of gem documentation that says you shouldn't have both bootstrap and bootstrap sockets (but then most of the advice I have received on this platform is the opposite) and that you shouldn't use the word 'require' in the css files when you use bootstrap sass (but I don't know how to replace that term (does 'import_tree' work?? I know it doesn't but what does??)

I have these links in my view:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
                                    <%= link_to icon('facebook', id: 'facebookauth'), user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %>
                                </div>  
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <%= link_to  icon('google',  id: 'googleauth'), user_omniauth_authorize_path(:google_oauth2) %>
                                </div>  
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <%= link_to icon('linkedin', id: 'linkedinauth'), user_omniauth_authorize_path(:linkedin) %>
                                </div>  
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <%= link_to icon('twitter', id: 'twitterauth'), user_omniauth_authorize_path(:twitter) %>
                                </div>
```

I have these css styles defined in a file called pages.css.scss:

```
.twitterauth {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    a:link {text-decoration:none; background-color:transparent; color:#55acee;};
    a:visited {text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent; color:#55acee;};
    a:hover {text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent; color:#E8CD08;};
    a:active {text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent; color:#55acee;};
}


.facebookauth {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  a:link {text-decoration:none; background-color:transparent; color:#3b5998;};
  a:visited {text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent; color:#3b5998;};
  a:hover {text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent; color:#E8CD08;};
  a:active {text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent; color:#3b5998;};
}



.linkedinauth {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  a:link {text-decoration:none; background-color:transparent; color:#007bb6;};
  a:visited {text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent; color:#007bb6;};
  a:hover {text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent; color:#E8CD08;};
  a:active {text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent; color:#007bb6;};
}


.googleauth {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  a:link {text-decoration:none; background-color:transparent; color:#dd4b39;};
  a:visited {text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent; color:#dd4b39;};
  a:hover {text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent; color:#E8CD08;};
  a:active {text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent; color:#dd4b39;};
}
```

When I render the page, it looks like ugly styling grey colour, black background on hover - gross. When I try inspecting the element, I'm expecting to see a reference to my css style as the closest thing to the content.

I see:

```
<i id="linkedinauth" class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
```

Usually, the inspect element section has a column which shows the relevant styles. Nothing in that column shows 'linkedinauth'. Instead, it shows labels called: inherited from a: and then sets out a set of ugly styling.

How do I get my app to use my styling?

I think this problem is specific to links, because the rest of my html is using bootstrap and the rest of my styling just fine.

I have another link in my file which I try to style as follows:

```
<%= link_to article.title, article, class: "extracttitle" %>
```

I have a css file called: articles.css.scss

```
.extracttitle {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  color: #003366;
  margin-top: 5px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-align:left; 
  padding-left:1px;
  a:link {text-decoration:none; background-color:transparent; color: #003366;};
  a:visited {text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent; color:#003366;};
  a:hover {text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent; color:#E50851;};
  a:active {text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent; color:#003366;};
}
```

Again, I've tried 20 different ways of styling the div tag to put this css on the article title, but the same ugly styling is forced on the element.

Can anyone see where I've got it wrong?

Following the suggestion below, I changed my application.css.scss, so that it now has:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "bootstrap-slider";
```

All of the styles i defined my other stylesheets don't get recognised. I've tried a lot of variations on @import tree. None of those work.

I found this blog post that suggests the whole file structure should be reorganised.
http://www.mattboldt.com/organizing-css-and-sass-rails/

ANOTHER ATTEMPT

When I try changing my application.css.scss to:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "bootstrap-slider";
@import "addresses.scss";
@import "articles.css.scss";
@import "common.css.scss";
@import "footer.css.scss";
@import "forms.css.scss";
@import "glyphs.css.scss";
@import "index.css.scss";
@import "legal.css.scss";
@import "navigation.css.scss";
@import "pages.css.scss";
@import "profiles.scss";
@import "video.css.scss";
```

The styles all appear to work (except for the links which still have the same problem I described above). So I'm still stuck for how to put styling on my link_to content.

Comment: You should `import` all of your SCSS files into application.css.scss and remove the comments/require statements. See the [Docs](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass).

Comment: The docs are completely confusing to me. How does the tree get included if not 'required'?

Comment: Also, the reason why I have imported files in different stylesheet files is that none of it worked when they were in a single list in application.css.scss together

Comment: This section of the docs doesnt make any sense to me:Then, remove all the *= require_self and *= require_tree . statements from the sass file. Instead, use @import to import Sass files.

Do not use *= require in Sass or your other stylesheets will not be able to access the Bootstrap mixins or variables.

Comment: Does it mean i need to write "import @pages.css.scss" and similar for every file I have in my stylesheets folder?

Comment: Generally speaking, yes. Use `@import`. `Require` stills works but your stylesheets may be out of order with that method. Do you literally mean no CSS files loaded when you originally had all your files in application.css.scss using `@import`?

Comment: No. See above,I expanded my question with more attempts at solving this. If i don't require tree, I don't get all the css defined in other files in my stylesheets folder. I can't figure out how to import the tree. It's super confusing to me. Before I begin completely rewriting my file strucute (as set out in the blog post) I want to try and understand how people use import for their css files